# Create string of multiple objects

Tags: django

I have something like this:

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_basket', verbose_name='Owner')
    name = models.CharField("Basket_Name", max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='BasketProduct', blank=True, null=True)

class BasketProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    basket = models.ForeignKey('Basket')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I try get all products from user `Basket` and create with their price and name string in the form of "Notebook - 2, PC - 5, Phone - 1"

My try:

```
user = request.user
b = Basket.objects.filter(owner=user)
bp = BasketProduct.objects.filter(basket=b)

for a in bp:
    a = '%s - %s' % (a.product, a.quantity)
    print a
```

This return something like this in shell:

```
[06/Oct/2012 19:44:41] "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
PC - 3 #single object
Notebook - 1 #second single object
```

I need: string = "PC - 3, Notebook - 1"

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the first three statements you are already doing. Then [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the array of intermediate results returned by looping over the queryset resulting from the first three statements:

```
', '.join(['%s - %s' % (a.product, a.quantity) for a in bp])
```